# Angular window open does not resize phonegap

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, cordova

Im using angularJS for my ionic phonegap application but i need to pop up an iframe, webview or browser (Anything that can be re-sizable)

I'm currently using

```
window.open(url, "mywindow1", "status=1,width=350,height=150");
```

But the above code completely ignores the height and width. Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but hope it will help you:--
replace your code like below

```
myWindow1 = window.open("", "status=1", "width=350, height=150");
```

Demo link
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_resizeto

Thanks

Comment: Still the same, its using the native ios browser so its not working like it would in web